# Choosing high performance PHP5 framework

Tags: yii, php

I'm exploring options for a PHP5 framework (to migrate old codebase).

Requirements:

- High performance (project gets ~10 million daily hits & is growing rapidly)
- Popular & mature
- Actively developed
- Good support of components & web services

What could be the options? Pros & cons.

I'm looking into Yii, Zend. But other options are welcome.

Also we have experience with Ruby On Rails so built-in similar ActiveRecord pattern would be great.

Comment: CodeIgniter is popular, and mature. Lightweight (~ high performance?). Unfortunately, not being maintained much anymore. CakePHP is another, as is Symfony.... however, subjective question, so now voting to close :(.

Comment: There is no such thing as a high performance framework. Frameworks are abstractions and toolkits for general purposes and common usecases. By that definition they will always be slower than a tailor made application dedicated to solving your particular problem.

Comment: The Zend Framework is high spec and very well documented and will probably always be upgraded and supported (it's developed by the guys who wrote php). it's bloated though, and even though it's well documented it's tough to work out how to use some of that functionality.

Comment: I wouldn't use a framework in a project with 10 million daily hits, for performance reasons, but skipping  that part, `Kohana` would be my first and only choice. It's currently the only framework I know that makes real use of HMVC. Check it at http://kohanaframework.org/

Comment: @Gordon ok, but some are better, some are worse at performance? :)

Comment: @Laurynas sure but if you expect 10mil daily hits the framework is the last thing to worry about. Its just one piece in the puzzle. The only advice I find reasonable to give is not to use a Full Stack framework but a component library so you dont have to tie into how the framework does things.

Comment: @Laurynas you'll probably get more help if you discuss this at the stackoverflow PHP chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Comment: Ok, thanks for tips! I just recently started actively using StackOverflow so I'm learning rules on the way ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Symfony](http://www.symfony.com/) will be a good option for you. Its somewhat similar to ROR. Now its version 2, which is php 5.3. You can use [symfoy 1.4](http://www.symfony-project.org/) or so, if you don't wish to choose 5.3. Regarding the performance, you can never expect high performance using any framework. You need to focus on other optimizations like caching, db replication etc.